# valgrind: instrumentation_tool, record when a fork occurs in parent

Tags: fork, valgrind, instrumentation

I'm curious if anyone (with a bit of Valgrind experience) has an idea how to tell Valgrind's coretool that a fork in the client has occurred.

Consider the simple profiling tool lackey. When one traces instructions with lackey and the client forks, you will have two "lackeys", one tracing the parent and the other tracing the child. However; I'm wondering if anyone has an idea how to "stop" the parent lackey at the point of the fork or shortly after.

Hope this makes sense, thoughts?

Comment: oh I should add, stop the instrumentation tool without modifying the client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured it out shortly after but neglected this answer until now.
Valgrind has the capability of tracking system calls thus actions can be taken pre and post system call invokation. The pub_tool interface has them happily waiting to be used and instrumented.

Answer (score 0):

no direct solution come to my mind. The only thoughts that come to my mind are dependent on task. If you are binary instrumentation in order to do some analysis, than you might like to separate "analysis" part into another process, thanks to that, only instrumented part forks, while you can decide with of them are connected to "analysis process" (and send log info there or what you want). I hope better solution will appear :).